# Python line too long for string with arguments

Tags: python

Hey I have the following code:

```
@node.route('/txions')
def transactions():
    txions_str = ""
    for txion in this_nodes_transactions:
        txions_str + "FROM: %s \n TO: %s \n AMOUNT: %d \n" % (txion['from'], txion['to'], txion['amount'])
    return txions_str
```

I get my Python linter complaining that the line is too long for `txions_str`, what is the correct way to format this line for when using mulitple parameters?

Comment: (`txions_str  +=  ` will work better)

Comment: better create a list, append & returned joined result.

Answer (score 2):

First, it's worth pointing out that you are returning an empty string there...

Anyways, you already have line breaks.

So, break your code to accommodate them

```
@node.route('/txions')
def transactions():
    txions = []
    for txion in this_nodes_transactions:
        txions.append("FROM: {} ".format(txion['from'])) 
        txions.append(" TO: {} ".format(txion['to']))
        txions.append(" AMOUNT: {} ".format(txion['amount']))
    return '\n'.join(txions)
```

Python also supports multi-line strings and line-continuation characters, but those dont seem needed here.